# How can i change the color of my div with class red

Tags: html

i'm new to html and want to color the div red. How can i add a color to this class? Thank you very much.

I've already tried to add css but it was blue. I want it to be red

```
.red{
color:#0024ff
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="red"></div>
```

UPDATE: Thanks but i've found a workaround. Friend of me suggested to remove the red class using javascript.

```
private function removeClass(){
 $('.red').addClass('red2');
}
```

And he gave me:

```
.red2{
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be blue? That's the hex value you gave it. Try googling "colorpicker" for a tool that will help you.

Comment: Don't put your answer in the question

Comment: What a nonsense!! You're creating a function named `removeClass` in which you're adding a class. What the fuzz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the correct color code for red #FF0000;.  Also use `background-color` if you want the div to be red - or `color` if you want the text to be red.

```
  .red{ background-color:#FF0000; } 


  .red{ color:#FF0000; }
```

You also shouldn't call your class ".red".  You should call it something that describes what the div is like "important-text".  This way if the style ever changes (say to Blue) the class name still makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

or simply use

```
<div style="color:red">
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the hex value of #0024ff it would be blue, order is RRGGBB with 0 being lowest value, so you have no red, tiny bit of green, and lots of blue specified

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for color RED.

```
<div style="color:#ff0000">
```

see also https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp